# Where can I find a .csv file of Strong's Greek Lexicon?

Tags: greek, resource-request, lexicon

I'm looking for a csv or excel file that has at least the listing of every word in Strong's lexicon and it's corresponding Strong's number. Is anyone aware of such a resource?

Answer (score 1):

> Matthias Müller has already given us the Koine Greek audio Bible. Now
>   he's produced another brilliant resource for those interested in
>   biblical languages. **It’s an Excel spread sheet of the entire Strong’s
>   concordance.**

https://christthetruth.net/2013/07/15/strongs-goes-excel/

I downloaded this about five years ago. It has both Hebrew and Greek. The Hebrew Strong's is all of them, not just to #5000. However, watch the Hebrew numbers as I found a discrepancy at that time (which may have since been corrected).

Edit: Added photo of Excel file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few formats at https://github.com/openscriptures/strongs -- not CSV, but you should be able to convert.